# referencing a gameObject from a c# interface event in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, casting, gameobject

I have an event manager in Unity which can handle events sent from scene components. The classes are all a bit abstracted from the standard Unity components. I am successfully able to fire an event from a button, and have that button's parent listen to the event (the `onEventReceived` you see below).

Using the Unity Debugger extension for VSCode, I can log the sender. If I type `sender.gameObject` and it returns a correct reference to the GameObject the sender is attached to. However, I cannot reference `sender.gameObject` within the `OnEventReceived` function itself - because it is of type `ISceneComponent` I suppose. How do I get a reference to the game object of the clicked sender?

[image]

Comment: What is the definition of ISceneComponent? I guess it doesnt have a gameObject-field? You could add a getGameObject() method on the interface and use that? Is there any case where sender is not a gameobject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into your issue myself before.

The fix is quite simple.

Assuming that you created the interface ISceneComponent, add the gameObject field to your Interface

```
public interface ISceneComponent
{
    GameObject gameObject { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

If the object implementing ISceneComponent also is a monobehaviour, gameObject will automatically be filled and you can reference it easily.